# Windows Hook based call - Potential GDI leak

Tags: c++, gdi+, memory-leaks

I am trying to make a call to my own function - from a program that I don't have control over - using hooks to paint on the same window of the program. It works for sometime but then crashes making me think this could potentially be a GDI leak or so. Wondering if anyone can look at this code and can comment from generic structure point of view and anything that can be improved up on. Second issue I have is the text would flicker every few seconds. Can any one be able to help in this regard? Please note that I am still a beginner when it comes to C++ GDI stuff. Thanks.

```
void Paint(HWND hWnd)
{
    HDC hdc = GetWindowDC(hWnd);
    HBRUSH Brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,0));
    HPEN   Pen = CreatePen(PS_DOT,1,RGB(255,255,0));
    HGDIOBJ PriorBrush = SelectObject(hdc, Brush);
    HGDIOBJ PriorPen = SelectObject(hdc, Pen);

    Gdiplus::Graphics g(hdc);
    Gdiplus::Pen pen(Gdiplus::Color(255, 255, 0, 0), 1);
    g.DrawLine(&pen,fpx,fpy,spx,spy);
    Font font(&FontFamily(L"Arial"), 12);
    LinearGradientBrush brush(Rect(0,0,100,100), Color::Red, Color::Yellow, LinearGradientModeHorizontal);
    Status st = g.DrawString(L"SampleText!", -1, &font, PointF((float)spx, (float)spy), &brush);
    assert(st == Ok);

    SelectObject(hdc,PriorBrush);
    SelectObject(hdc,PriorPen);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd,hdc);
    return;
}
```

//

Making the above call using:

```
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        LRESULT l = CallWindowProc(hook, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        Paint(hWnd);
        return l;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're leaking `Brush` and `Pen` - you need to use `DeleteObject` after selecting them out of the DC.

(Or get rid of them - are they even used?)

Comment: Thanks Richie - As my function is being called by another program - I am trying to store the old Brush & Pen before returning the control back to the Original program and is the reason I am storing them here. Should I use before Releasing DC?
 SelectObject(hdc,PriorBrush);
 SelectObject(hdc,PriorPen);
 DeleteObject(Pen);
 DeleteObject(Brush);
 ReleaseDC(hWnd,hdc);
 return;

Comment: @ejuser: There are no "old" brush and pen, because they belong to the DC and you've created your own, which you use and then destroy.

Comment: Thanks Richie. Would Delete Brush & Pen. Do I have to do anything about the Font & Graphics as well or can I leave them as they are?

Comment: - Sorry - Trying to figure out how to post the resulting code as a comment - it seems to get mixed up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does this code looks fine now? Thanks

```
void Paint(HWND hWnd)
{
     HDC hdc = GetWindowDC(hWnd);

Gdiplus::Graphics g(hdc);
Gdiplus::Pen pen(Gdiplus::Color(255, 255, 0, 0), 1);
g.DrawLine(&pen,fpx,fpy,spx,spy);
Font font(&FontFamily(L"Arial"), 12);
LinearGradientBrush brush(Rect(0,0,100,100), Color::Red, Color::Yellow, LinearGradientModeHorizontal);
Status st = g.DrawString(L"SampleText!", -1, &font, PointF((float)spx, (float)spy), &brush);
assert(st == Ok);

DeleteObject(&pen);
DeleteObject(&brush);

ReleaseDC(hWnd,hdc);
return;
}
```

Comment: Didn't want this to be an answer but don't know how to post the Formatted code in Comments :(

Comment: The above code - Seems to be functioning normally for few minutes - which is a good sign ( would know more on this in a day or so ). However the flickering text issue(Every 10 seconds or so once) is still there and wondering if there is any thing that can be done to get rid of that flickering? Thanks

Comment: @RichieHindle - An update on this - The program has been running without any crashes for more than a day and I think in a better shape now. One Question related to Graphics object 'g' here - Does it has be deleted as well with DeleteObject(&g) after the delete brush command? Wondering if there are any links available - which describes on the best method to "delete" or "cache" the objects etc. Thanks.